# Active Directory Federation Services in ruby?

Tags: ruby, active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs

So, ADFS is new to me. We have a client that will be using it. I've been doing research and the documentation Microsoft provides seems overly complicated. Is there a simple tutorial that someone can follow to properly integrate ADFS? I was hoping it was simple like OAuth, but that does not seem to be the case.

I was hoping someone here can point me in the right direction, because I'm somewhat lost.

Thanks.

Comment: ADFS cares not who's communicating with it, be it a .NET web app or a Ruby site. So long as your Ruby app can communicate with it in one of the available formats, which are a variety of WS-* web service methods or through passive redirection. Your app will need to understand and be able to parse RSTR tokens, though. Whether there is a Ruby gem for that or not I dunno, not being a Ruby fellow myself.

Answer (score 1):

You mention ruby in the title but not in the question? How exactly do you want to integrate ADFS? Federate, add a Relying Party, add a web service? With what?

Please provide more detail.

There's a ton of stuff [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2735.ad-fs-2-0-content-map.aspx).